# Does this middle variable have any information gain?

Tags: entropy, information-gain

Let's say that I have 2 variables: `A` (as the input) and `C` (as the output)
So it's `A -> C`
There's also another variable `B`, and
`corr(A, B) > corr(A, C)`
`corr(C, B) > corr(A, C)`
Would `A -> B -> C` get better performance with the existing model?
In other words, does this `B` have any information gain?

Answer (score 0):

The information gained about C, given A is: `log(1/P(A,C))`. The information gained about C, given both A and B is: `log(1/P(A,B,C))`. So as long as `P(A,C) > P(A,B,C)`, there will be more information gained by including B.

Now, whether or not that's the case depends on what you're using for the `corr` metric. But if A/C are dependent on B, there will be at least some values of B which are giving information gain. In general, I'd always include dependent variables in a model, unless the dependence is *too* strong, in which case some models may not work as well (e.g. neural networks).